# mousemove over a div under an image

Tags: javascript, mousemove

I have a the following situation: a div, with bars in it (divs with a certain height) to show a chart.
On top of the main div with the bars, an image a mask is placed, so you can see figures instead of bars. (I have a man and a woman to show stats, see attached image for example).

The bars are attached to a mousemove event to show information about the bars in a tooltip.

If I hover over the bars my mousemove does not show, because the image is blocking it.
Is it possible to hover over the image, and still have the mousemove event bound to the bars to get the information I want? The end result is to show a tooltip with the info from the bars.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make some additional divs on top of the image, and use them for the hovering. But that could get a bit messy.

Or you can make a HTML image map with four areas, each with an onmouseover property, which would be a lot cleaner:

```
<MAP NAME="mymap">
    <AREA SHAPE="RECT" COORDS="0, 0, 100, 400" HREF="" OnMouseOver="tooltip('bar1')" NAME="bar1">
    <AREA SHAPE="RECT" COORDS="100, 0, 100, 400" HREF="" OnMouseOver="tooltip('bar2')" NAME="bar2">
    <AREA SHAPE="RECT" COORDS="200, 0, 100, 400" HREF="" OnMouseOver="tooltip('bar3')" NAME="bar3">
    <AREA SHAPE="RECT" COORDS="300, 0, 100, 400" HREF="" OnMouseOver="tooltip('bar4')" NAME="bar4">
</MAP>
<IMG SRC="mybarmask.png" USEMAP="#mymap" />
```

The coords here are most likely wrong, I'm not on my computer so I can't test it...

Comment: Your first comment "_You could make some additional divs on top of the image, and use them for the hovering_" did it for me I now have a div with bars in it. On top of that, the masked image. On top of that, a copy of the first div with the bars but then transparent. This seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your are of equal width, you would need to:

1. find offset of your container:

   `var DOMOffset = function(el) {
       var curleft, curtop;
       curleft = curtop = 0;
       if (el.offsetParent) {
           do {
               curleft += el.offsetLeft;
           curtop += el.offsetTop;
       } while (el = el.offsetParent);
       }
       return [curleft,curtop];
   }`
2. attach to your image listeners for all events you'd like to handle, and bind them to a function which would delegate them to a proper DOM element. something like `Math.floor((event.clientX - container_offset_X) / count_of_your_bar * width_of_your_bar)` should give you zero-based index of the proper bar element.
   Delegation itself can be done using modification of the following code:

   ```
   quickDelegate = function(event, target) {
       var eventCopy = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
       eventCopy.initMouseEvent(event.type, event.bubbles, event.cancelable, event.view, event.detail, event.pageX || event.layerX, event.pageY || event.layerY, event.clientX, event.clientY, event.ctrlKey, event.altKey, event.shiftKey, event.metaKey, event.button, event.relatedTarget);
       target.dispatchEvent(eventCopy);
   };
   ```

   where `event` is your original event caught by your image and `target` is your bar DOM element which you have detected.

please note that I wrote this delegation function some time ago, and I was only targeting Firefox and Chrome. you'll probably need to fix something to make it work IE's.

Answer (score 0):

mouseenter and mouseleave will work even through other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach (solution) to this problem:

For each of those figures I would have two images, one is blank inside so just the border of the figure and one is completely colored (orange) from top to bottom.

then you could have something like this :

```
<div class="empty">
    <div class="full">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

the `.empty` has the empty image as `background` with the proper height and width and `position:relative`. `.full` has the colored fully colored image with the adjusted `height` but fixed width and `position:absolute; bottom: 0; left=0`.

then on mouseover on `.empty` or `.full` you can do whatever you want